# Unable to fetch Prometheus metrics into Splunk

Tags: prometheus, splunk

Unable to fetch Prometheus metrics into Splunk.

I have used the "Prometheus Metrics for Splunk" plugin from the Splunk Apps.
Both Prometheus and Splunk are installed on the local Windows machine.
Tried to fetch data using Prometheus remote write-

Prometheus configuration

```
- url: "http://localhost:8098"
  authorization:
    credentials: "ABC123" #replace with my splunk access token
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  write_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: expensive.*
    action: drop
```

Splunk Configuration

```
[prometheusrw]
port = 8098
maxClients = 10

[prometheusrw://856412]
bearerToken = ABC123
index = prometheus
whitelist = *
sourcetype = prometheus:metric
disabled = 0
```

Prometheus error logs:

```
ts=2022-07-12T11:40:22.139Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=info remote_name=856412 url=http://localhost:8098 msg="Done replaying WAL" duration=10.5184238s
ts=2022-07-12T11:40:22.438Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=warn remote_name=856412 url=http://localhost:8098 msg="Failed to send batch, retrying" err="Post \"http://localhost:8098\": EOF"
```

Suggest corrections/ways to get prometheus data to Splunk.

Comment: what configuration(s) do you have for Prometheus? What error(s) do either Splunk or Prometheus report?

Comment: I have updated the question with Prometheus error log.

Comment: The Prometheus error shows it can't send to the HTTP Event Collector. Verify your token, sourcetype, index, etc are all correct. Make sure there are no firewall rules between (or on) the systems blocking traffic.  *Right now* this looks like a network/connectivity issue, not a "Splunk" or "Prometheus" one :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems Prometheus remote_write sends data in protobuf format, which is not consumed by many 3rd party monitoring tools, including Splunk HEC.

I ended up using Splunk OTEL collector with Prometheus receiver.